# Drei Dinge zusammen sind eine Trias. Was aber sind vier und fünf?

Tags: single-word-request

In gehobenem Stil spricht man, wenn man eine Einheit von drei Dingen (oder Menschen) meint, bisweilen von einer

> Trias

Das Word geht zurück auf ein spätlateinisches Wort *trias*, siehe auch *Triade*. Das Duden Universalwörterbuch vermeldet uns zu Triade:

> 1. [spätlateinisch trias (Genitiv: triados) < griechisch triás, zu: tría, Neutrum von: treĩs = drei] (bildungssprachlich) Dreizahl, Dreiheit.

Was aber sage ich - in nämlicher Sprachebene - wenn ich zwei, vier oder fünf Objekte habe, die ich so ansprechen will? *Duo*, *Quartett* und *Quintett* kommt mir einen Tick zu ungehoben vor (und vielleicht auch zu sehr an die Musik gebunden, was *Trias* definitiv nicht ist).

**Die Frage ist:** Gibt es bildungssprachliche (spätlateinische, griechische, etc.) Ausdrücke für Zweiheit, Vierheit und Fünfheit, die man hier einsetzen könnte?

Hier noch zum Kontext:

Ein Gesprächspartner aus der Kulturszene sagt:

> Also zum Beispiel an einem Theater ist es meistens die Trias... oder die... die... die Vier... Vierschaft zwischen... es gibt einen Intendanten, es gibt einen Chefdramaturgen, es gibt einen Technischen Direktor, und es gibt einen Chefdisponenten.<sup>1</sup>

Offensichtlich fehlte dem Gesprächspartner das passende Wort.

---

<sup>1) Im Original verwendet der/die Gesprächspartner/in auch weibliche Formen; dies habe ich hier der Schlankheit wegen weggelassen. Nichts gegen weibliche Formen, aber Schlankheit ist manchmal auch gut.</sup>

Comment: Je nach Kontext könnte Quadriga passen.

Comment: Die Frage ist schon bedenklich dicht an *Gibt es ein schönes Fremdwort für …?*. Wenn *Vierheit* es trifft und von praktisch jedermann verstanden würde, warum weitersuchen? Aber das Bemühen, sich verständlich auszudrücken, wird im Deutschen gerne einem angestrebten Sprachniveau untergeordnet.

Comment: @Guidot  Na ja. "Vierheit" ist schon sehr gekünstelt. Ich wette, das kommt seltener irgendwo vor als "Trias". Und im gegebenen Fall war es ja nur eine aus der Not geborene Ersatzkonstruktion des Sprechers, der uns das Viergespann, das ein Theater führt, vorstellen wollte.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: der hat aber ja auch "Vierschaft" gesagt, das klingt wirklich ausgedacht. "Vierheit" finde ich schon deutlich besser. Sofort für jeden verständlich und trotzdem hohes Sprachniveau. "Viergespann" ist für Menschen, die zusammen ein Theater leiten, natürlich wirklich gut, weil es Vierspänner als Kutschen schon gibt, ist aber für Dinge dann nicht mehr das Richtige, und "Fünfgespann" ist erst recht schief.

Answer (score 12):

Ist zwar weder lateinisch noch griechisch aber X-gestirn scheint hier gut zu passen: Dreigestirn, Viergestirn, Fünfgestirn, Sechsgestirn, ...

Comment: Nicht was ich erwartete, aber sehr schön aus der Schachtel gedacht! Mir fiel kurz vorher noch das *Viergespann* ein. Aber dein Gestirn gibt dem Grüppchen noch einen ironischen Glanz...

Answer (score 4):

Es handelt sich um die Tetrade (Vierheit) und die Pentade (Fünfheit) usw. bis zur Dekade (Zehnheit)
!

Answer (score 3):

Es liegt nahe, sich hier an die Mathematik zu halten, die sich Begrifflichkeiten für Zahlengruppen erarbeitet hat. Diese Begriffe lassen sich auf reale Dinge ebenso anwenden:

> Tripel, Quadrupel, Quintupel, ... , n-Tupel

Das *Tripel* hat es schon ziemlich weit (wesentlich weiter als das *Trias*) in die Umgangssprache geschafft - Seine englische Ausprägung, *Triple*, wird z.B. im Sport verwendet.

Answer (score 2):

- Prime, Sekunde, Terz, Quarte, Quinte, Sexte, Septime, Oktave, …
- Solist, Duett, Terzett, Quartett, Quintett, …; Orchester.
- Solo, Duo, **Tri**o, (Quattro/Quadro?)
- Monade, Dyade, **Tri**ade, Tetrade (Olympiade), Pentade, Hexade, Heptade, …
- —, Biga, **Tri**ga/Troika, Quadriga.

  - —, Tandem, Random.
- Singular, Dual, **Tri**al; Paukal, Plural.
- Einzel, Doppel/Dupel/Paar, **Tri**pel, Quadrupel, Quintupel, Sextupel, ...; *n*-Tupel.
- Monas, Dyas, **Tri**as, Quadras?/Tetras?

Answer (score 0):

Wie wäre es mit dem schönen Tetraktys?

Comment: Vorschlag gut, Antwort aber etwas dünn, weswegen der Bewertungs-Bot gemosert hat.

Answer (score 0):

Wie wäre es mit *Viererbande* .. ?