# Wort wie »Begriffspaar«, aber für drei Begriffe

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche einen Ausdruck, mit dem man drei zusammengehörige Begriffe beschreiben kann.
Insbesondere geht es um das *Allgemeine*, das *Besondere* und das *Einzelne* bei Hegel.

Für zwei Begriffe gibt es das Begriffspaar:

> ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Begriffspaar):) Paar zweier zusammengehörender, einander [gegensätzlich] entsprechender Begriffe

Mir ist für drei Begriffe zunächst die *Trias* eingefallen, aber *Begriffstrias*?

Gibt es einen passenderen Ausdruck oder ist es verständlicher, von einem Begriffssystem (mit drei Begriffen) zu sprechen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drei Dinge zusammen sind eine Trias. Was aber sind vier und fünf?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/47645/drei-dinge-zusammen-sind-eine-trias-was-aber-sind-vier-und-f%c3%bcnf)

Comment: @tofro: es geht hier speziell um einen Begriff der Philosophie, also **kein Duplikat hier** (außerdem wird in der anderen Frage nach 4 und 5, aber nicht nach 3 gefragt).

Comment: Wer sich freiwillig mit Hegel befasst, wird auch *Trias* bzw. Komposita davon akzeptieren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neben [Trias und Triade](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triade_(Philosophie)) hört man in der Philosophie auch den Begriff [Triplizität](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Triplizit%C3%A4t), den [Hegel selbst benutzt](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Hegel,+Georg+Wilhelm+Friedrich/Vorlesungen+%C3%BCber+die+Geschichte+der+Philosophie/Dritter+Teil.+Neuere+Philosophie/Dritter+Abschnitt.+Neueste+deutsche+Philosophie/B.+Kant) hat.

> - Es sind nach Kant zwölf Grundkategorien, die in vier Klassen zerfallen; und es ist merkwürdig und ein Verdienst, daß jede Gattung wieder eine Dreiheit ausmacht. Die **Triplizität**, diese alte Form der Pythagoreer, Neuplatoniker und der christlichen Religion, kommt hier, wiewohl ganz äußerlich, wieder hervor. <sup>[G.W.F. Hegel: Vorlesungen über die Geschichte der Philosophie](http://www.zeno.org/Philosophie/M/Hegel,+Georg+Wilhelm+Friedrich/Vorlesungen+%C3%BCber+die+Geschichte+der+Philosophie/Dritter+Teil.+Neuere+Philosophie/Dritter+Abschnitt.+Neueste+deutsche+Philosophie/B.+Kant)</sup>
> - Ebensowenig ist – nachdem die Kantische, noch erst durch den Instinkt wiedergefundne, noch tote, noch unbegriffne **Triplizität** zu ihrer absoluten Bedeutung erhoben, damit die wahrhafte Form in ihrem wahrhaften Inhalte zugleich aufgestellt und der Begriff der Wissenschaft hervorgegangen ist – derjenige Gebrauch dieser Form für etwas Wissenschaftliches zu halten, durch den wir sie zum leblosen Schema, zu einem eigentlichen Scheinen, und die wissenschaftliche Organisation zur Tabelle herabgebracht sehen. <sup>[G.W.F.Hegel: Phänomenologie des Geistes - Kapitel 6](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/phanomenologie-des-geistes-1656/6)</sup>

Allein der christlichen Theologie vorbehalten ist der Begriff [Trinität](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreifaltigkeit).

Answer (score 4):

Eine Dreiergruppe nennt man auch [Tripel](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Tripel) oder [Triplett](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Triplett). Wie wäre es daher mit *Begriffstripel* oder *Begriffstriplett*?

Google-Suchen nach dem jeweiligen Wort fördern ein paar Treffer zutage, sie scheinen also grundsätzlich beide in Verwendung zu sein, ersteres z.B. [im Wikipedia-Artikel zu "Begriffssystem"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffssystem#Begriffstripel). Zweiteres hat deutlich weniger Fundstellen, und wird dort meist mit nur einem einfachen *t* am Ende geschrieben, z.B. [in dieser Diplomarbeit](https://books.google.de/books?id=RlB-AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=%22Begriffstriplet%22&source=bl&ots=xpf6qM-FKj&sig=Z5J9pKsQqfbZavIK5F6JthdM774&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6md2GsuPfAhUDJ1AKHfJNASYQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Begriffstriplet%22&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

Für drei zusammengehörende Dinge gibt es den Begriff

> Triset

[Quelle](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Triset)

auch wenn dieser meiner Meinung nach ziemlich ungebräuchlich ist.

**Edit**:

Ein weiterer möglicher Begriff wäre die

> Triade

steht es auch sonst für die [Dreiheit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triade) in verschiedenen Bereichen.

Ich finde allerdings auch das von @Hand-Jakob vorgeschlagene Tripel/Triplett passend.

Comment: Also *Begriffstriset*?

Comment: Ich würde eher den Begriff als solches verwenden und vorher im Text definieren woraus es besteht.